# Marionette CollectionView: how to check whether item is added because of "reset" or "add"?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using Marionette's `CollectionView` to render a list of items with `ItemViews`. Whenever a new item is added, I want to run a short fade-in animation. But not when the collection is rendered initially (or the collection is reset).

Before using Marionette, I handled the `reset` and `add` events slightly differently, but I can not figure out how to do this here. I looked at the source code and it seems that `addItemView` is responsible for adding the child view and both `addChildView` (called when `add` is triggered on the collection) and `render` (for `reset` events) call this method.

Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

Include these functions in your `CompositeView` declaration:

```
onBeforeRender: function(){
  this.onBeforeItemAdded = function(){};
},

onRender: function(){
  this.onBeforeItemAdded = myAnimation;
}
```

This is similar to the solution I present in my book on Marionette (https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction/)

How it works: Marionette triggers the "before:render" before it renders the entire collection, so you can set the the `onBeforeItemAdded` function to do nothing. Once the collection has been rendered, set that function to animate the new item view.

Since each time the collection view adds an item view it also triggers the "before:item:added", you can define an `onBeforeItemAdded` function that will automatically be called when that event is triggered. This matching happens thanks to triggerMethod.

This solution should solve your problem, without your needing to add flags on the model.

Comment: This is awesome! It might be worth adding that the item view is the first argument in `onBeforeItemAdded`, so you can call `view.on('show', myAnimation)` for a smoother result.

Answer (score 2):

David Sulc answer is pretty hacky, fadeIn should be defined within item it self, not within parent view.
Another thing is that onBeforeItemAdded() is not mentioned in documentation, so it could be for internal use and may change over time.

What I suggest is to add following to parent view, note flag parentRendered:

```
    itemViewOptions: function() {
        return {
            collection: this.collection,
            parentRendered: this.rendered
        };
    },
    onRender: function() {
        this.rendered = true;
    }
```

and use that flag in onShow function inside item view:

```
    onShow: function() {
        // show visual effect on newly added items
        if (this.options.parentRendered) {
            this.$el.css('opacity', 0).slideDown(200).animate(
                { opacity: 1 },
                { queue: false, duration: 400 }
            );
        }
        else {
            this.$el.show();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best choice is to bind your event after the CollectionView has been rendered.

```
myCollectionView.on( "render", function() {
   this.on( "after:item:added", executeMyAnimation );
});
```

Comment: This works fine with `CollectionView`, but not with `CompositeView` which I ended up using for other reasons. `CompositeView` does not re-render itself entirely when the collection is `reset` but only re-renders the item views for the collection. The way it is setup in my app, is that the view is first rendered with an empty collection, which is later fetched (and reset). `CompositeView` has an event `composite:collection:rendered` but there is no "before", so there is no way for me to disable the animation callback. I ended up with an "animate" flag on the model.